# facebook api: count attendees for event (limit problem)

Tags: php, facebook, graph

Okay normally I'm all fine about the facebook API but I'm having a problem which just keeps me wondering. (I think it's a bug (Check ticket http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=13694) but I wanted to throw it here if somebody has an idea).

I'm usng the facebook PHP library to count all attendees for a specific event

```
$attending = $facebook->api('/'.$fbparams['eventId'].'/attending');
```

this works without a problem it correctly returns an array with all attendees...

now heres the problem:

This event has about 18.000 attendees right now.
The api call returns a max number of 992 attendees (and not 18000 as it should).

I tried

```
$attending = $facebook->api('/'.$fbparams['eventId'].'/attending?limit=20000');
```

for testing but it doesn't change anything.

So my actual question is:

If I can't get it to work by using the graph api what would be a good alternative? (Parsing the html of the event page maybe?) Right now I'm changing the value by hand every few hours which is tedious and unnecessary.

Comment: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=75457
It's a known issue on Facebook's side that has not been resolved yet.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there are two parameters, `limit` and `offset`. I think that you will have to play with both and continue making calls until one returns less than the max. limit.

Something like this, but in a recursive approach (I'm writting pseudo-code):

```
offset = 0;
maxLimit = 992;
totalAttendees = count(result)

if (totalAttendees >= maxLimit)
{
  // do your stuff with each attendee
  offset += totalAttendees;
  // make a new call with the updated offset
  // and check again
}
```

Comment: I'll give it a quick try I get your idea

Comment: Fiddled around a bit but didn't get it to work yet, going to bed now 0am in Germany I'll check it tomorrow

Comment: The result remains the same, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I've searched a lot and this is how I fixed it:
The requested URL should look something like [this](https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/738667559524648?access_token=603913936305026%7CyZYvULhJhDcrsVaGzJmendOpHDw&fields=attending_count,invited_count).

[Here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=738667559524648%3Faccess_token%3D603913936305026%257CyZYvULhJhDcrsVaGzJmendOpHDw%26fields%3Dattending_count%2Cinvited_count&version=v2.2) is where you can test it and here is the code I used:

```html
function events_get_facebook_data($event_id) {
  if (!$event_id) {
    return false;
  }

  $token = klicango_friends_facebook_token();
  if ($token) {
    $parameters['access_token'] = $token;
    $parameters['fields']= 'attending_count,invited_count';
    $graph_url = url('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/' . $event_id , array('absolute' => TRUE, 'query' => $parameters));
    $graph_result = drupal_http_request($graph_url, array(), 'GET');
    if(is_object($graph_result) && !empty($graph_result->data)) {
      $data = json_decode($graph_result->data);
      $going = $data->attending_count;
      $invited = $data->invited_count;
      return array('going' => $going, 'invited' => $invited);
    }
    return false;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

SELECT eid , attending_count, unsure_count,all_members_count   FROM event WHERE  eid ="event"