# How to get user count by status of facebook events (attending, Invited, etc..)

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is there any way to get the user count by status of facebook events? Facebook does this on the event page (the left columng with each status has a count next to it), but could not find any documentation on how to do the same. It needs to work for small or large events. For small events, I can easily get the list of users and do a quick count. But for events with over 1000 users, the previous method is too slow and not acceptable.

Comment: check GZveri answer on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398463/facebook-api-count-attendees-for-event-limit-problem/26743062#26743062

Comment: @GZveri The answer below has been updated with new fields available for the Event object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a better way than count every list of users as explained below.

> You can which users are 'attending' an event by issuing an HTTP GET to /EVENT_ID/attending
>
> You can which users have replied 'maybe' to an event by issuing an HTTP GET to /EVENT_ID/maybe
>
> You can which users are declined an event (i.e. responded 'no') by issuing an HTTP GET to /EVENT_ID/declined
>
> You can which users have not replied to an event by issuing an HTTP GET to /EVENT_ID/noreply

Taken from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/

UPDATE 28-Jun:

As of today, Facebook added new fields to the Event FQL table that allows you to do exactly what you want.

From the developers blog:

> We've added the following fields to the event FQL table to make it
>   easier to get the counts of users RSVP-ed to an event:
>
> all_members_count
>   attending_count
>   unsure_count
>   declined_count
>   not_replied_count

They're pretty much self-explanatory.

Comment: Right, I need the count of each of those lists.  On large lists, each of those calls you  mentioned take quite some time.

Comment: Ah, misread the question sorry. I don't believe that there's a better way to do it, not even with FQL. I will update my answer

Comment: That is unfortunate, can there really be no other way?

Comment: Don't think so, there's no field (in the Graph or FQL) referring to the number of invited users.

Comment: No, you've got to return the whole list of attendees and count them in your application. Neither FQL nor the Graph API have a count method. Some tables will return a count of their members. Unfortunately `event_member` isn't one of them.

Comment: Is it possible with a GET Link?